# Images saved through slides API aren't editable in presentation?

Tags: google-workspace, google-slides-api

We're attempting to create a new presentation and position images on slides. When using create_image it saves image but can't move or resize? Does that capability not exist?

If we open the new presentation and add a slide in Google, we are able to edit without any issues.

Following https://developers.google.com/slides/api/guides/add-image

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `position images on slides. When using create_image it saves image but can't move or resize?`. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.